# (1,5-1)*2 = 8 JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,  есть выражение, (1,5-1)*2 на js оно будет равно 8, это происходит, потому что стоит запятая, а не точка, Объясните пожалуйста, почему js игнорирует единицу и считает выражение, как (5-1)*2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

Оператор "запятая" вычисляет все операнды (слева направо) и возвращает значение последнего операнда.

Таким образом

```js
var a = (1,5-1);
console.log(a); // 4
```

Comment: А зачем это вообще, если левые операнды в конце концов игнорируются?

Comment: @simplygood - в статье по ссылке есть примеры кода

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо

Comment: @simplygood, они не игнорируются.