# Поясните результат выполнения скриптов

Tags: javascript

- Почему результат равен 4?

  ```js
  let obj = {
   "0": 1,
   0: 2
  };

  alert( obj["0"] + obj[0] );
  ```
- Сумма равна 12, потому что он сложил строки, но почему откинул
  скобки?

  ```js
  [] + 1 + 2
  ```
- А этот самый не понятный - почему 8?

  ```js
  let a = (1,5 - 1) * 2;

  alert(a);
  ```

Comment: Лучше задавать по одному вопросу в вопросе, а не по несколько

Comment: @Grundy, а вот и главный дубликатор. Какое отношение первый вопрос имеет к этому? Кстати, у меня где-то был ответ про числовые индексы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там про алгоритм оператора `+` :) надо третий найти про ключи, я помню что-то было про повторяемость, ты еще писал типа сначала запретили, потом опять разрешили когда вычисляемые ввели

Comment: @Grundy отличные ответы в приведённых ссылках. Спасибо. Постараюсь лучше гуглить(

Comment: @Grundy, вроде всё нашёл, передубликатил немного. А то, про что ты вспомнил - [вот](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436060/178988), но вроде к теме не относится? Впрочем, в дубликате тоже упоминается про дублирование ключей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log({ "0": 1, 0: 2 }); // same property defined twice
console.log([].toString()); // empty string
console.log((1,5 - 1)); // operator , returns the last operand
```

Comment: Подобное `console.log((1,5 - 1));` кроме тестов и вопросов на собеседовании может в реальной практике встречаться?

Comment: Если быть точным, оператор возвращает последний операнд, а не второй (тоже не понимаю, зачем это нужно).

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf вы абсолютно правы. Почитал тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: @doox911, может, но крайне редко. Само собой, не в таком виде. И, вероятно, если линтер не используется.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, скорее всего, перетащили из Си, как и другие конструкции. Иногда удобно, если несколько действий логически связаны. Кстати, в си в макросах можно применять - гораздо удобнее, чем `do { ... } while(0);`. А ещё, чтобы скобки не ставить (впрочем, в js скобки обычно ставят всегда).

Answer (score 1):

Ключами в объекте могут быть только строки, либо Symbol. В данном случае  `0` приводится к строке `"0"` и в объекте добавляется всего одно поле. Убедиться в этом можно просто выведя полученный объект:

```js
let obj = {
  "0": 1,
  0: 2
};

console.log(obj);
```

---

[Оператор `+`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-addition-operator-plus) применяет к своим аргументам внутреннюю функцию [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toprimitive), для массива это равносильно вызову `.toString()`, литералы чисел остаются числами.

Далее, если хотя бы один из операндов строка, все остальные тоже приводятся к строке и происходит конкатенация строк.

В итоге получается `[].toString() + 1 + 2` -> `"" + 1 + 2` -> `"1" + 2` -> `"12"`

---

Ответ на следующий вопрос подробно описан здесь: [(1,5-1)*2 = 8 JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600457/186999)